Morphism of tensor functors in rigid tensor categories
This is a cross-post from MSE.
$\require{AMScd}$
The following proposition (1.13) is given in Tannakian Categories (loosely paraphrased with some change in notation).

Assume that $(F,c),(G,d):\mathcal{C} \rightrightarrows \mathcal{C}'$ are tensor functors. If $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{C}'$ are both rigid tensor categories, then every morphism of functors (my comment: natural transformation, I presume) $\lambda:F \Rightarrow G$ is an isomorphism.

The proof given in Tannakian Categories looks like this.

The morphism $\mu:G \to F$ making the diagrams
\begin{CD} 
F(X^{\vee}) @>\lambda_{X^{\vee}}>> G(X^{\vee})\\ 
@VV\simeq V @VV\simeq V\\ 
F(X)^{\vee} @>{}^{t}(\mu_{X})>> G(X)^{\vee} 
\end{CD}
commute for all $X \in \mathcal{C}$ is an inverse for $\lambda$.

Now, I feel quite lost in how to actually prove this. A footnote in the same article at the end of the page gives us that one can either use Yoneda lemma or the discussion here: Functors on rigid tensor categories.
The second link in turns gives us the following link: Morphism between tensor functors which has a diagram that seem quite messy. Any clarification on what to focus on to understand this proof would be appreciated.
Which proof is conceptually clearer; the one involving Yoneda lemma or working through the diagram in the last link (Morphism between tensor functors)?
Comment: Perhaps I should have waited longer before crossposting; my lack of patience in this regard got the better of me.

The result does not require $\mathcal{C}'$ to be rigid. But of course a monoidal functor with rigid domain will have rigid image, so any nonrigidity in $\mathcal{C}'$ is not seen by the problem.
Anyway, the structure of the argument goes:

Suppose $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}'$ is a (strong) monoidal functor, and $X \in \mathcal{C}$ is a dualizable object. Then $F(X)$ is dualizable, with duality data given by applying $F$ to the duality data for $X$. Idea of proof: suppose $(X^\vee, \mathrm{pairing}, \mathrm{copairing})$ are duality data for $X$. This means that they have prescribed domain and codomain, and importantly that a certain equation (called "zig-zag" or "zorro" or "snake" or "triangle" or probably other things depending on what school you come from) holds. But functors preserve equations.
Suppose $\lambda : F \Rightarrow G$ is a monoidal natural transformation, and $X$ is a dualizable object with dual $X^\vee$. Then $\lambda_X : FX \to GX$ is invertible, with inverse the transpose of $\lambda_{X^\vee}$. Let's type-check this: $\lambda_{X^\vee} : F(X^\vee) \to G(X^\vee)$, but $F(X^\vee) \cong (FX)^\vee$, and this isomorphism is canonical by step 1 together with the uniqueness of dual objects. Idea of proof: It suffices to prove that $\mathrm{pairing}_{GX}(\lambda_X \otimes \lambda_{X^\vee}) = \mathrm{pairing}_{FX}$, and similarly for $\mathrm{copairing}$. But this is immediate from naturality and monoidality of $\lambda$.
This suffices: if a monoidal natural transformation takes invertible values on objects, then its is monoidally invertible. Idea of proof: It is standard that if a natural transformation takes invertible values, then it is invertible — the main thing to show that the inverse values are also natural, but this is easy. The other thing is to show that the inverse transformation is monoidal; again this is essentially straightforward.


For a string diagrammatic proof, you can look at p9 of my course notes: https://people.math.osu.edu/penneys.2/8110/Notes/FusionCat.pdf. As Theo points out, rigidity is only required for the domain monoidal category.

Addressing Theo Johnson-Freyd: Is your $\mathrm{pairing}$ and $\mathrm{copairing}$ the evaluation map $\text{ev}: X \otimes Y \to \mathbf{1}$ and coevaluation map $\epsilon:\mathbf{1} \to X \otimes Y$ that Deligne/Milne mentions on page 12 in Tannakian Categories?
@DavePenneys Sadly, I am not too comfortable with string diagrams. =)

@Ben123 Yes. Other names are "evaluation/coevaluation" and "counit/unit".
